# R - Substracting rows from one data frame based on date and other value in another data frame

Tags: r

I would like to remove some rows from the reports_example data frame (See below) based on the Month column and the Park column of the `AC_example` data frame (also below). I would like the first Month of the reports_example data frame to either be the same or to come after the `AC_example` data frame.

Here is a subset of the two data frames in question:

```
reports_example <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  Month        Park
  2019-12-01   Aspen_Heights
  2020-02-01   Aspen_Heights
  2020-05-01   Aspen_Heights
  2021-06-01   Aspen_Heights
  2019-11-01   Auburn_Bay
  2020-03-01   Auburn_Bay
")

AC_example <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  Month        Park
  2020-05-01   Aspen_Heights
  2020-06-01   Aspen_Heights
  2020-07-01   Aspen_Heights
  2021-04-01   Aspen_Heights
  2020-03-01   Auburn_Bay
  2021-03-01   Auburn_Bay
")
```

I would like the final report data frame to look like this:

```
reports_final_example <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  Month        Park
  2020-05-01   Aspen_Heights
  2021-06-01   Aspen_Heights
  2020-03-01   Auburn_Bay
")
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to use the `fuzzyjoin` package. A "semi" join will include rows in the first data.frame where it can find a match in the second data.frame. The join will match on `Park`, and on `Month` (where the `Month` of the first data.frame comes after that of the second data.frame).

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

fuzzy_semi_join(
  reports_example,
  AC_example,
  by = c("Park" = "Park", "Month" = "Month"),
  match_fun = c(`==`, `>=`)
)
```

**Output**

```
       Month          Park
3 2020-05-01 Aspen_Heights
4 2021-06-01 Aspen_Heights
6 2020-03-01    Auburn_Bay
```

Comment: That worked, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`

```
reports_example %>% 
mutate(Month_example = as.Date(Month)) %>% 
left_join(AC_example %>% mutate(Month_AC = as.Date(Month)), by = 'Park') %>% 
filter(Month_example >= Month_AC) %>% 
select(Park, Month_example, Month_AC) %>% 
distinct(Park, Month_example)
```

Results in:

```
           Park Month_example
1 Aspen_Heights    2020-05-01
2 Aspen_Heights    2021-06-01
3    Auburn_Bay    2020-03-01
```